# How can i access my mails from every computer within the domain

Tags: outlook, active-directory, exchange-server

we are using Office 365 with Exchange Online and Microsoft Outlook.

Is it possible so everybody with an Exchange account can access his mails in Outlook no matter on the computer(within the domain) he is logging in.
Right now if i log in on another computer there is no email account set up. So i need to add the account everytime im on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [ZeroConfigExchange](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/outlooking/2015/10/30/zeroconfigexchange-automating-the-creation-of-an-outlook-profile-for-exchange-online-accounts-and-exchange-on-premises-environments/), it supports Exchange Online.

> Implementing ZCE
>
> Implementing ZCE is easy.  It can be added (through a login script) to
>   the user's registry or as a GPO for all users. Here's how:
>
> 1. In the Windows Registry, navigate to the appropriate subkey for each version of Outlook that is in use:
>
> For Outlook 2016:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover
>
> As a policy:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover
>
> For Outlook 2013:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover
>
> As a policy:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover
>
> For Outlook 2010
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover
>
> As a policy:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover
>
> For Outlook 2007:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover
>
> As a policy:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover
>
> 2. Once the key is created, right-click in the right pane and click New, click DWORD Value and type in “ZeroConfigExchange” (without the
>      quotes) and then press ENTER.
> 3. Finally, right-click ZeroConfigExchange, click Modify and then in the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.